# Hide div with AngularJS with Django-rendered template

Tags: django, angularjs

I have a HTML form rendered by Django template tag and I want to manipulate it using AngularJS.

In my template (not rendered) I have:

```
<html>
   <body>
       {{ form.as_p }}
   </body>
</html>
```

This is how Django renders this template:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form>
        <div id="div_id_street" class="ctrlHolder ">
        <label for="id_street">
            Street<span>*</span>
        </label>
        <input id="id_street" type="text" class="textInput textinput" name="street" maxlength="32">
        </div>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to hide the div **div_id_street**, but I am not able to add the ng-show or ng-hide directive in my HTML because of the way that Django generates the HTML code.

Is it possible inside an AngularJS controller to show/hide this div?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the HTML generated by Django after Angular compiles it?

Comment: The HTML is generated before Angular compiles it.

Comment: So you can get Django to add "ng-controller='...'" somewhere but you can't get it to add "ng-show='...'" somewhere else?  Can you get Django to add a class (which will be a directive) to the target div?

Comment: It is possible, but to do that I need to change parts of the Django core.

The solution that will be perfect for me is to be able to change the CSS property _display_ to _none_ (to hide the div) or remove this property (to show the div), within an Angular controller.

Comment: I'm still missing something... in your Django-rendered template, where is the ng-controller?  BTW, it is possible to modify the DOM from inside a controller.  I just first want to know if you can even attach a controller.  Or do want to create a `ctrlHolder` directive?  (If so, @CaioToOn's answer will work.)

Comment: Doing the example code I forgot to put ngController. But there is a controller in <body> tag.

Comment: Have you tried adding the directive as a class, or just as an attribute? ie: class="cntrlHome ng-hide:expression"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible inside an AngularJS controller to show/hide this div?

Yes, but this "goes deep against the Angular way" -- [Misko](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/SYglWP_x7ew/lFtb75NWNWUJ).  Inject $element, then use selectors to find and manipulate.  $element is set to the element that your controller is defined on.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $element) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.$watch('show', function (value) {
    if (value) {
        $element.find('#div_id_street').show();
    } else {
        $element.find('#div_id_street').hide();
    }
  })
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPmrS/) -- in this fiddle I used ng-controller.

Answer (score 4):

I was wrong. It is possible to change the template of a Django rendered form.

When defining a django form, I am able to change the widget of each fiels, so I can put the Angular directives in the widget.

For example:

```
# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    street = forms.CharField(max_length=80, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'ng-model': 'street',
            'ng-show': 'false',
            'ng-change': 'validateStreet()',})
        )
```

This will be rendered as:

```
<div id="div_street" class="ctrlHolder">
    <label for="id_street">Street</label>
    <input ng-model="street" name="street" maxlength="80" ng-change="validateStreet()"
      ng-show="false" type="text" class="textInput textinput ng-valid ng-dirty"
      id="id_street">
</div>
```

So in my controller I can manipulate this whole field.

Comment: Good, I'm glad you got Django to do it instead.  You'll probably want ng-show tied to a $scope property.

Comment: But angularJs remove initial value when we update data using form instance in Django

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify the template, neither add a class to that specific DIV to add it a `ng-show`, than you should create a directive to handle this DOM manipulation. You shouldn't do DOM manipulation from within a controller. As [stated by the DOCs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller),

> Do not use controllers for:
>
> - Any kind of DOM manipulation — Controllers should contain only
>     business logic. DOM manipulation—the presentation logic of an
>     application—is well known for being hard to test. Putting any
>     presentation logic into controllers significantly affects testability
>     of the business logic. Angular offers databinding for automatic DOM
>     manipulation. If you have to perform your own manual DOM manipulation,
>     encapsulate the presentation logic in [directives]http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
> - ...

I would suggest you to `$watch` the property you need and manually show/hide the element from inside the `link` function of a directive.

Comment: Agreed. It is not the way AngularJS must be used.

But I found a way to change my template. It was a lack of Django knowledge :-)

I will post the solution here.